# Does a URL with fragment (#) require a path?

Tags: http, url

Is it correct (standard) to write a URL like this (with fragment, without path)?

```
https://example.com#something
```

Or the correct form is this (with a slash to represent the empty path)?

```
https://example.com/#something
```

I see that most browsers simply rewrite the first form (`#`) into the second (`/#`), but I wonder if the first form is correct based on the URL / HTTP *standard*. I can't find a clear information.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.